# How to implement "Update App" mechanism

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is it possible to implement "Update Available and Install" mechanism for app which is not submitted to App Store.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, not submitted to the app store. Like for an ad-hoc or enterprice app?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [iVersion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion) which leverages the application bundle identifier to check if a new version of an application has been uploaded to iTunes (using the publicly available iTunes feed).

Because of the bundle id trick you should be just fine, meaning you can safely embed it in the first version you release to the App Store.

As for the non-App Store releases the iVersion provides a simple mechanism of checking for a new version from a plist at given URL. Moreover for beta ad-hoc builds you should take a look at [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) which aims at helping people with distribution of their apps outside the AppStore (however for beta builds only).

Comment: But the question is for app not submitted to the App Store.

Comment: Ok, then I did not get the question exactly. So you mean like ad-hoc/enterprise distribution?

Comment: Looking for ad-hoc app actually.

Comment: Ok, then you check the TestFlight SDK (link in the answer), that feature is baked into it. You could also take a look at HockeyApp or Apphance, they provide similar features when it comes to ad-hoc releases (however different level of "additional" features). Check them out and see which one would work best for you!

Comment: You can still use iVersion for this - just supply a URL that points to a plist that iVersion should check for updates, and specify the URL to download the app from.